# Colletting element from different DataFrames into arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

I like using nested data structures and now I'm trying to understand how to use Pandas

Here is a toy model:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2],'y':[10,20]})
b=pd.DataFrame({'x':[3,4],'y':[30,40]})
c=[a,b]
```

now I would like to get:

```
sol=np.array([[[1],[3]],[[2],[4]]])
```

I have an idea to get both `sol[0]` and `sol[1]` as:

```
s0=np.array([item[['x']].ix[0] for item in c])
s1=np.array([item[['x']].ix[1] for item in c])
```

but to get sol I would run over the index and I don't think it is really pythonic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want just the `x` columns from `a` and `b`. You can concatenate two Series (or DataFrames) into a new DataFrame using [pd.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#concatenating-objects):

```
In [132]: pd.concat([a['x'], b['x']], axis=1)
Out[132]: 
   x  x
0  1  3
1  2  4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now, if you want a numpy array, use the [values attribute](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s):

```
In [133]: pd.concat([a['x'], b['x']], axis=1).values
Out[133]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

And if you want a numpy array with the same shape as `sol`, then use the [reshape method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
In [134]: pd.concat([a['x'], b['x']], axis=1).values.reshape(2,2,1)
Out[134]: 
array([[[1],
        [3]],

       [[2],
        [4]]], dtype=int64)

In [136]: np.allclose(pd.concat([a['x'], b['x']], axis=1).values.reshape(2,2,1), sol)
Out[136]: True
```

Comment: It looks fine but I still have a doubt since I would like to use the list c and not its elements explicitly.

Comment: Then use `pd.concat([df['x'] for df in c], axis=1)`.